# Create lists using loops in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, variables

I've been working on a webpage scraper and I would like to create separate lists containing different elements. There would have to be more than a 1000 lists and I am trying to run that through a for loop. I need the lists to be appropriately named according to the element in each particular iteration. I tried using globals() to achieve this but it only takes an int or a char and not a string.
Is there a way to achieve this?

For an example:
If `people = ['John', 'James', 'Jane']`
I need 3 lists named
`Johnlist=[]`
`Jameslist=[]`
`Janelist=[]`

Below is what I tried but it returns an error asking for either an int or a char.

```
for p in people:
   names = #scrapedcontent
   globals()['%list' % p] = []
   for n in names:
      globals()['%list' % p].append(#scrapedcontent)
```

Comment: You don't need this. You want a dictionary. Having random names floating in your namespace is a design mistake that will make your life very difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly discourages you to use `globals`, `locals` or `vars` As suggested by @roganjosh, prefer to use dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

people = defaultdict(list):
for p in people:
    for n in names:
        people[p].append(n)
```

Or

```
people = {}
for p in people:
    names = #scrapedcontent
    people[p] = names
```

**DON'T USE THIS**

```
for p in people:
    names = [] #scrapedcontent
    globals().setdefault(f'list_{p}', []).extend(names)
```

Output:

```
>>> list_John
[]

>>> list_James
[]

>>> list_Jane
[]
```

Comment: Great suggestion but the data wont work in this way. Each p in the people list has multiple names. its like a relationship list for example
JohnList will contain James, Kim, Harry because John has a relation with these names.
and I dont believe dictionaries are they way for this. 
Any other suggestions would really help a lot.

Comment: @Glad. `globals()` returns a dict so a dict is the right way to do what you want and safe.

Comment: @Glad. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I realize that its a bad practice but its just a personal project that I'm working on and I need a way to scrape all the data before I can start working on it.

Answer (score 0):

try to do it in a dict:

for example:

```
d = {}

for p in people:
  d[p] = []
  names = ...      
  d[p].extend(names)
```

Comment: Great suggestion but the data wont work in this way. Each p in the people list has multiple names. its like a relationship list for example
JohnList will contain James, Kim, Harry because John has a relation with these names.
and I dont believe dictionaries are they way for this. 
Any other suggestions would really help a lot.